# Error at running Simulink FMU in ROS: "Creation of dllfmu failed"

Tags: simulink, fmi

I'm trying to run a Simulink FMU in ROS for a co-simulation in Gazebo. I've been able to simulate and validate the FMU in Python but, when I try to load it in ROS, I'm obtaining an error.

I'm trying the The problem was that ROS wasn't able to find the binaries for Linux (fmu_traject.so file inside binaries/linux64) since the FMU was exported in Windows 10 and I was trying to load it in Ubuntu 18.04. The solution has simply been to export the FMU from MATLAB-Simulink installed in the Ubuntu machine.next commands from [this](https://link-springer-com-s.caas.cn/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-45956-7_7?error=cookies_not_supported&code=e24eb343-3aba-4440-9266-e5e2b7ef45d4) guide.
In terminal 1:

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
cd ~/FMI/Trajectory # The path where the FMU is
ros2 run fmi_adapter fmi_adapter_node __params:=my_params.yaml
```

Just in case, the file `"my_parmas.yaml"` just contains the path to the FMU:

```
fmi_adapter_node:
  ros__parameters:
    fmu_path: '/home/ubuntu1804/FMI/Trajectory/fmu_traject.fmu'
```

In terminal 2:

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
ros2 lifecycle set /fmi_adapter_node configure
ros2 lifecycle set /fmi_adapter_node activate
```

Just after running `ros2 lifecycle  set /fmi_adapter_node configure`, the following is printed in terminal 2:

```
Transitioning failed
```

And the next error appears in terminal 1:

```
[ERROR][FMI2XML] Start attribute is required for this causality, variability and initial combination
[FATAL][FMILIB] Could not change to the DLL directory /tmp/fmi_adapter_DrX8pj/binaries/linux64/
[FATAL][FMILIB] The FMU contains no binary for this platform.
[ERROR] []: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[ERROR] []: Original error: Creation of dllfmu failed!
[WARN] []: Error occurred while doing error handling.
```

In addition, I've also tested to create a launch file and run it in the following way.

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
cd ~/FMI/Trajectory # The path where the FMU is
ros2 launch SimulinkFMU_launcher.launch.py
```

I'm attaching below the launch file `"SimulinkFMU_launcher.launch.py"`, which is entirely based on the mentioned guide.

```
import ament_index_python.packages

import launch
import launch.actions
import launch.launch_description_sources
import launch.substitutions


def generate_launch_description():
    # fmu_path = (ament_index_python.packages.get_package_share_directory('fmi_adapter_examples') +
    #             '/share/DampedPendulum.fmu')
    fmu_path = 'FMI/Trajectory/fmu_traject.fmu'

    fmi_adapter_description = launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        launch.launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            ament_index_python.packages.get_package_share_directory(
                'fmi_adapter') + '/launch/fmi_adapter_node.launch.py'),
        launch_arguments={'fmu_path': fmu_path}.items())

    description = launch.LaunchDescription()
    description.add_action(fmi_adapter_description)

    return description
```

This is the log I obtain with the launch file:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu1804/.ros/log/2022-04-27-09-24-45-820715-ubuntu-13445
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [fmi_adapter_node-1]: process started with pid [13462]
[fmi_adapter_node-1] [ERROR] []: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[fmi_adapter_node-1] [ERROR] []: Original error: Given FMU file 'FMI/Trajectory/fmu_traject.fmu' not found or cannot be read!
[fmi_adapter_node-1] [WARN] []: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.lifecycle_node]: Failed to make transition 'TRANSITION_CONFIGURE' for LifecycleNode '/fmi_adapter_node'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that ROS wasn't able to find the binaries for Linux (fmu_traject.so file inside binaries/linux64) since the FMU was exported in Windows 10 and I was trying to load it in Ubuntu 18.04. The solution has simply been to export the FMU from MATLAB-Simulink installed in the Ubuntu machine.